# WordPress Category, Child Category, Active Category Problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

`Let's say I went to a category page. There is some content on this category page. I would like to show all the child categories of the parent category of this category below the content or under this category page. I would also like to show the description and thumbnail image of the category. How do I do that?

Then if a user goes to a category page from the menu, that category will remain active. The rest of the categories will be blur, inactive or something like that.

**UPDATE:**

Let's say it's a menu. Now all the category items have been added in this menu. Now if anyone clicks on parent or sub-category from here, all the sub-categories of the parent category of that category will be shown. Like the code below. All right.

But when someone clicks on a category from the menu, that category will be highlighted. The rest of the categories will be in blur or something like that. But if you hover the mouse, that blur will no longer exist.

I would have benefited if someone helped. Any ideas?

[image]

```
if( is_product_category() ){

$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$child_terms    = get_term_children ( $queried_object->term_id, 'product_cat' );
$based_term     = (is_wp_error($child_terms) || empty($child_terms)) ? get_term ( $queried_object->parent, 'product_cat' ) : $queried_object;

printf( '<h2 class="shop__sidebar-heading"><a href="%s?so64231449=true">%s</a></h2>', esc_url(get_term_link($based_term->term_id)), $based_term->name );

$display_terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'orderby'       => 'name', 
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'    => false,
    'parent'        => $based_term->term_id,
) );

if( !empty( $display_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $display_terms ) ){

    echo '';
  
        foreach( $display_terms as $display_term ){

            $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta ($display_term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
            $image        = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
            
            printf(
                '<div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="content-inner">
                        <h6%s><a href="%s">%s</a></h6>
                        <img src="%s" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>',
                ($display_term->term_id == $queried_object->term_id) ? ' class="active"' : '',
                esc_url(get_term_link($display_term->term_id)),
                $display_term->name,
                $image,
            );
        }

    echo '';
   
}
```

}

Comment: A little while ago you solved a problem for me. I would like to highlight the active category of that category. The rest of the categories want to do something like blur. I replayed there, see please ..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67102659/displays-the-child-category-of-wordpresss-parent-category-with-woocommerce/67103362#67103362

Comment: Sure, Please put that code here. and also can you give me some screenshots? how will it look like?

Comment: Please see my update details

Comment: highlight the active category on hover or default on page load?

Comment: 1. The active category will be highlighted when the page loads. The rest of the categories will be blurred.

2. But if you mouse in the blur category, there will be no blur. If you don't hover again, it will be in blur.

Comment: Share page link.

Comment: Which page link ?

Comment: where you want to achieve.

Comment: I am working on a local server............

Comment: Can you do CSS?

Comment: please see my update

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.category-box').hover(
       function () {
            $('.category-box').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    );
});
```

```css
.sub-cat-list {
    width: 100%;
}

.sub-cat-list .content-inner {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.sub-cat-list .content-inner img {
  width: auto;
  height:120px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.sub-cat-list  .content-inner h6 {
  padding: 10px 0;
 }

 .sub-cat-list .content-inner h6 a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
 }

 .sub-cat-list .content-inner h6 a:hover {
  color: #CC0066; 
 }

// All are testing purpose

 .category-box {
     background: blue;
 }

 .category-box:hover {
     background: red;
 }

 .category-box.active {
  background-color: #e7e7e7
  
}

.category-box.active h6 a {
  color: cayan;
}

.category-box.active:hover > h6 a {
  color: rgb(228, 22, 66);
}
.col-md-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
.col-md-3.category-box {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
.col-md-3.category-box.active {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -moz-filter: blur(0px);
    -o-filter: blur(0px);
    -ms-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="sub-cat-list">
        <div class="col-md-3 category-box active">
            <div class="content-inner">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
                    <h6><a>This is a cat heading 1</a></h6>
                </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 category-box">
            <div class="content-inner">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
                    <h6><a>This is a cat heading 2</a></h6>
                </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 category-box">
            <div class="content-inner">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
                    <h6><a>This is a cat heading 3</a></h6>
                </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 category-box">
            <div class="content-inner">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
                    <h6><a>This is a cat heading 4</a></h6>
                </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add active class on first category box using counter variable.

```
if( is_product_category() ){

    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $child_terms    = get_term_children ( $queried_object->term_id, 'product_cat' );
    $based_term     = (is_wp_error($child_terms) || empty($child_terms)) ? get_term ( $queried_object->parent, 'product_cat' ) : $queried_object;

    printf( '<h2 class="shop__sidebar-heading"><a href="%s?so64231449=true">%s</a></h2>', esc_url(get_term_link($based_term->term_id)), $based_term->name );

    $display_terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
        'orderby'       => 'name', 
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'    => false,
        'parent'        => $based_term->term_id,
    ) );

    if( !empty( $display_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $display_terms ) ){

        echo '';
            $i = 0;
            foreach( $display_terms as $display_term ){

                $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta ($display_term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
                $image        = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
                
                $class = ( $i == 0 ) ? 'active' : '' ;

                printf(
                    '<div class="col-md-3 category-box '.$class.' ">
                        <div class="content-inner">
                            <h6%s><a href="%s">%s</a></h6>
                            <img src="%s" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>',
                    ($display_term->term_id == $queried_object->term_id) ? ' class="active"' : '',
                    esc_url(get_term_link($display_term->term_id)),
                    $display_term->name,
                    $image,
                );
                $i++;
            }

        echo '';
       
    }
}
```

Add class on `category-box` on hover called 'active' and based on do CSS.

```
function add_custom_js(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.category-box').hover(
                   function () {
                        $('.category-box').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                   }, function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                   }
                );
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_custom_js', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: What you don't understand?

Comment: did you check `category-box` have class on hover?

Comment: Are u active ??

Comment: @cholonto yes tell me.

Comment: I probably didn’t understand you well. I say again, when a user clicks on a category from the menu and comes to the category page, the page will look like the screenshot above after it is loaded. That is, Active or Current category will be highlighted. The rest of the categories will be blurred.

Comment: Yes as per your requirement I added an active class on the category box. and also added on hover on category. you just need to add CSS based on that class.

Comment: I checked it again now. Is working. But there are some problems.
I want - the current category will be active when a user comes to the category page by clicking from the menu. The rest of the categories will have something like blur or opacity less. Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231197/discussion-between-bhautik-and-cholonto).

Comment: I tried again. All right.
First, I removed the hover from the jQuery.

But there is a problem. For example, like the picture above and the way the code is done, when I come to the sub-category of the main category, only the first category is active.

For example: there are 5 main categories. Each main category has sub-categories at 6/7. When I go to a category, only the first sub-category in that category is active. The rest of the categories are not active. Any solution?

Comment: can you create a snippet with HTML and javascript?

Comment: Please check below comment & snippet with HTML and javascript...

Comment: All right. However, the problem remains. When I go to a category, only the first sub-category in that category is active. The rest of the categories are not active. This means that the first category of the main category remains active. But if you go to the next category, it is not active.

Comment: what you asked in the original question I answered and it works. also, you should put correct HTML with all categories and subcategories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231379/discussion-between-cholonto-and-bhautik).

Answer (score 0):

```js
           $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.category-box')(
               function () {
                    $('.category-box').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
               }, function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
               }
            );
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
.sub-cat-list {
    width: 100%;
}

.sub-cat-list .content-inner {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.sub-cat-list .content-inner img {
  width: 220px;
  height:120px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.sub-cat-list  .content-inner h6 {
  padding: 10px 0;
 }

 .sub-cat-list .content-inner h6 a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
 }

 .sub-cat-list .content-inner h6 a:hover {
  color: #CC0066; 
 }

// All are testing purpose

 .category-box {
     background: blue;
 }

 .category-box:hover {
     background: red;
 }

 .category-box.active {
  background-color: #e7e7e7
  
}

.category-box.active h6 a {
  color: cayan;
}

.category-box.active:hover > h6 a {
  color: rgb(228, 22, 66);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sub-cat-list">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="content-inner">
                    <img src="" />
                    <h6><a>This is a cat heading 1</a></h6>
                </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="content-inner">
                    <img src="" />
                    <h6><a>This is a cat heading 2</a></h6>
                </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="content-inner">
                    <img src="" />
                    <h6><a>This is a cat heading 3</a></h6>
                </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="content-inner">
                    <img src="" />
                    <h6><a>This is a cat heading 4</a></h6>
                </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```